# Desinstalar VPN4Test de UBUNTU

Tags: ubuntu, vpn

Acabo de instalar VPN4test en UBUNTU, el programa no funciona asi que intento desinstalarlo. El problema, es que no puedo. Ni por la teminal ni por central de software.

Esta es la línea de comando que brinda la 
página para la instalación:

```
wget -q-0 https://download.vpn4test.com/files/linux_installer.sh | sh
```

Y la de run:

```
./.local/bin/VPN4Test.AppImage
```

Ya busque algún archivo para desinstalar en esa ruta y no encontré nada.